# iOS-redux updation not working Works fine in android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

Problem :
Redux updation is not reflecting in UI in iOS

Code

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {this.props.children}
    {this.props.showNightOutFeedback &&
      this.props.remainderNightoutFeedbackId &&
      this.props.remainderNightoutFeedbackId.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups &&
      this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
        queueActionTypes.ROUTE_FEEDBACK_POPUP && (
        <FeedbackRatingScreen
          routeName={
            (this.props.nightOutDetails &&
              this.props.nightOutDetails.route_name) ||
            "Feedback for Route"
          }
          routeID={this.props.remainderNightoutFeedbackId[0]}
          visible={this.props.showNightOutFeedback}
          rating={
            (this.props.nightOutDetails &&
              this.props.nightOutDetails.total_rating) ||
            0
          }
          onClose={() => {
            this.props.showNightOutFeedbackModal(false);
            this.props.deQueue();
          }}
        />
      )}

    {this.props.showVenueFeedback &&
      !isObjectEmpty(feedbackObj) &&
      this.props.queueingPopups &&
      this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
        queueActionTypes.VENUE_FEEDBACK_POPUP && (
        <FeedbackAndRatingComponent
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          data={feedbackObj ? feedbackObj : {}}
          onClose={data => {
            this.props.showVenueFeedbackFun(false);
            this.props.updateFeedbackIsCompleted(data, true);

            if (
              this.props.remainderNightoutFeedbackId &&
              this.props.remainderNightoutFeedbackId.length
            ) {
              this.props.showNightOutFeedbackModal(true);
            }
            this.props.deQueue();
          }}
        />
      )}
    {this.props.user &&
      // this.props.showInviteScreenModal &&
      this.props.queueingPopups &&
      this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
        queueActionTypes.INVITE_SCREEN_POPUP && (
        <InviteScreen
          isInvite={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.isInvite}
          inviteId={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.inviteId}
          nightOutID={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.nightoutId}
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          navigateBack={this.props.navigateBack}
        />
      )}

    {this.props.user &&
      // this.props.showInviteScreenModal &&

      this.props.queueingPopups &&
      this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
        queueActionTypes.INVITATION_ALERT_POPUP && (
        <InviteScreen
          isInvite={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.isInvite}
          inviteId={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.inviteId}
          nightOutID={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.nightoutId}
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          navigateBack={this.props.navigateBack}
        />
      )}

    {this.props.user &&
      // this.props.showInviteScreenModal &&
      !this.props.enterRoute &&
      this.props.queueingPopups &&
      this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
        queueActionTypes.INVITATION_START_POPUP && (
        <InviteScreen
          isInvite={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.isInvite}
          inviteId={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.inviteId}
          nightOutID={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData.nightoutId}
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          navigateBack={this.props.navigateBack}
        />
      )}
    {!this.props.venues.enterVenues &&
      //showModal.active &&
      //this.props.venues.venueDetails.venue_enter[0] != undefined &&
      (this.props.queueingPopups &&
        this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
        this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
          queueActionTypes.ENTER_VENUE_POPUP &&
        (shouldShowPopUpOrNot && (
          <EnterRoutePopup
            navigation={this.props.navigation}
            visible={true}
            isFreeRun={
              this.props.venues.venueDetails.venue_enter.length &&
              this.props.venues.venueDetails.venue_enter[0].isFreeRun
            }
            data={this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupData}
            message={""}
            onCloseModal={() => {
              showModal.active = false;
              this.props.closeModal();
            }}
            onClose={() => {
              showModal.active = false;
              this.props.closeModal();
              this.props.deQueue();
              // this.props.isPopupActiveFun(false);
            }}
          />
        )))}

    {this.props.isVenueLoading &&
      this.props.queueingPopups &&
      this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
        queueActionTypes.LOADING_VENUE &&
      VenueData.isVenueInARClicked && <LoaderPopup onClose={() => {}} />}

    {this.props.showNavigateModalPopup &&
      this.props.queueingPopups &&
      this.props.queueingPopups.length > 0 &&
      this.props.queueingPopups[0].popupName ===
        queueActionTypes.NAVIGATE_VENUE_POPUP && (
        <EnterRoutePopup
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
          visible={this.props.showNavigateModalPopup}
          isFreeRun={true}
          data={
            this.props.venueNavigateData ? this.props.venueNavigateData : {}
          }
          onClose={() => {
            this.props.showNavigateModalPopupFun(false);
            // this.props.isPopupActiveFun(false);
            this.props.deQueue();
          }}
        />
      )}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

}

```
mapStateToProps,  mapDispatchToProps
```

is used to connect my queueReducer .

```
    const popupQueuingReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case queueActionTypes.ENQUEUE: {
      let data = [];
      data = state.queueingPopups;
      let currentQueueData = null;

      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: data
      };
    }
    case queueActionTypes.PUSH: {
      let data = state.queueingPopups;
      // data.indexOf(action.data) == -1 &&
      let currentQueueData = null;
      currentQueueData = {
            popupName: action.data.popupName,
            popupData: action.data.queueData
          };
          data.unshift(currentQueueData);


      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: data
      };
    }
    case queueActionTypes.REMOVE_ENTER_VENUE: {
      let data = state.queueingPopups;
      data = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item !== queueActionTypes.ENTER_VENUE_POPUP;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: data
      };
    }

    case queueActionTypes.REMOVE_LOGOUT: {
      let data = state.queueingPopups;
      data = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item !== queueActionTypes.LOGOUT;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: data
      };
    }

    case queueActionTypes.REMOVE_VENUE_LOADING: {
      let data = state.queueingPopups;
      data = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.popupName !== queueActionTypes.LOADING_VENUE;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: data
      };
    }
    case queueActionTypes.REMOVE_PAUSE_POP_UP: {
      let data = state.queueingPopups;
      data = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.popupName != queueActionTypes.PAUSING_POP_UPS;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: data
      };
    }

    case queueActionTypes.DEQUEUE: {
      let currentData = [];
      currentData = state.queueingPopups;
      if (currentData.length > 0) {
        currentData.shift();
      }
      // state.queueingPopups.length && state.queueingPopups.shift();

      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: currentData
      };
    }

    case queueActionTypes.EMPTY_QUEUE: {
      let data = state.queueingPopups;
      data = data.filter(function(item) {
        return (
          item === queueActionTypes.PAUSING_POP_UPS ||
          item === queueActionTypes.USER_MENU_POPUP
        );
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: data
      };
    }
    case queueActionTypes.RESTORE_STATE:
      console.log("action.data" + action.data);
      return {
        ...state,
        queueingPopups: action.data
      };

    default:
      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
};

export default popupQueuingReducer;
```

Working Scenario Explanation :

In adding certain alerts to queue(array) in my queueReducer and once am finished with one array I remove the item from queue. This change is supposed to pop the subsequent array type in my queue as any change in reducerState would be reflected in my js file since they are connected via mapStateToProps. This works fine in android but in iOS its not the expected bahaviour.

Is this got something to with Platform or code ??

Am totally confused as why its not working as it is simple state updations not something related to platform or so

Can anyone point me out what's wrong here ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT 1**

Props are getting updated in store. As I can totally confirm that every single alert I want is in my queue and when each time my queue value changes componentWillReceive props is updated with new value. But am not able to see the reflection in UI

**EDIT 2**

Since @HMR pointed out as enqueue doesn't alter the array queue I tried changing two enqueue alert type to push but the results are same

**EDIT 3**

```
 let dataToQueue = {
  popupName: queueActionTypes.NAVIGATE_VENUE_POPUP,
  queueData: data
};
dispatch(pushQueue(dataToQueue));
```

The above method is used to dispatch my event

Comment: shift and unshift mutates your state and `case queueActionTypes.ENQUEUE:` is not doing anything to the state.

Comment: but the element is added right ? then how come this works in android ? will try t change it to push and let you know. Thanks for the support man

Comment: I tried changing two of incoming alerts from enqueue to push still the same result

Comment: You updated your question but didn't update the code you are currently using.

Comment: @HMR I updated the question